# Passing variable to another page

Tags: php

My brick wall is that I am running this code on 2 pages.

```
session_start()
$selectbegindate = $_POST['begindate']; 
$selectenddate = $_POST['enddate']; // End date
$begindate = new DateTime($selectbegindate);
$enddate = new DateTime($selectenddate);
```

Form:

```
<form action = "index.php" method="post"><!-- Begin date select form -->
                Begin Date: <input type="date" id="begindate" name="begindate">
                End date: <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </form
```

Immediately below the form and on the test 2nd page I have:

```
<?php
if(isset($submit)) {
  $_SESSION["begindate"] = $_GET["begindate"];
  $_SESSION["enddate"] = $_GET["enddate"];
}
?>
```

First page: I can submit a begin date and an end date through an HTML form and my page works as expected, running SQL statements, producing charts, etc. My issue comes when I navigate to the test page, which has the code above, I get:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: begindate in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\sessionstest.php on line 14
```

Line 14 in the test code above.

I'm sure this is a duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef) but I think what I need is different since the user can change the variables on the next page.

I would like to use `SESSION` as it seems the most viable.

I have tried understanding isset and isempty but not having any luck applying it to what I need.

Should I use anything in the `a href` links in the html section?

Thanks for any help.

Edited 6/10/2018 to include the form code.

Comment: Store the data in a session then it will be available on multiple pages.

Comment: what is the code of your form where you're sending the data to this page?

Comment: What is your form action...? mean POST or GET

Comment: There are many ways to share variables between different pages , you could use sessions, cookies, php classes, include a php script on both pages via `include('common.php')` etc.

Comment: once your error was because of `$_SESSION["begindate"] = $_GET["begindate"]` you would see error message about 'undefined index' rather 'undefined variable'.

Comment: So the posted variable is never making it from the first page to the second page, correct?